# What is the best way to get mouse position over form?

Tags: c#, .net, mouse, onmousemove, mouse-position

**I want the best way to get mouse position for Form.**

I,m now set the values of mouse position in variables to get them in another methods "Like Form1_Click".

Is there any better way to do that??.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How does this work for you?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmousemove.aspx

Another alternative is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition.aspx

then to get it on the form use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
xm=System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - this.Location.X
ym=System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - this.Location.Y
```

then you should do:

```
xm - form border x 
ym - form border y
```